# How to combine (mean) different index length DataFrames with NaNs inside?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two DataFarmes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2, np.nan, 6, 7], columns=['A'])
```

I want to combine then into a third one, thus achieving the following result:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([1.5, 2, 4.5, 7], columns=['A'])
```

However I struggle to find a way to do this. Mainly because:

1. I want to combine based on some index and each have different length, but same columns
2. Each have `np.nan` at different places. In such cells I want to take the one with value, no have `np.nan`
3. In the case when they both have a value for a given index location, I would like to aggregated based on `mean`

How can I achieve that?

What I tried:

I thought about converting `np.nan` to 0 and then combining and dividing by two (or the number of DataFrames) however this results in artificially low data points, due to the conversion to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `mean` by duplicated index values:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).mean(level=0)
#working like
#df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).mean()
print (df)
     A
0  1.5
1  2.0
2  4.5
3  7.0
```